# Redirect if route is matched but there is no data for that id value

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router, react-redux

This is route for project :

```
<Route exact path="/party/:partyId/" component={PartyContainer} />
```

Data is collected in Party in componentDidMount,

```
fetchWishlist(currentId);
```

Party is Connected with function in party.Container throught mapActionToProps.

How to redirect user to another page if there is no data for particular ID?

Thanks in advance guys :).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

this.props.history.push('path')

Answer (score 0):

In component PartyContainer you can check if data for particular ID exists if not

```
return <Redirect to="/404" push={false} />
```

or

```
this.props.history.push("/404")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your routes in a [Switch](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Switch) statement:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path= "/party/:partyId/" component = {PartyContainer}/>
    <Route exact path="/party/:partyId/partyDetails" component={PartyDetails} />
    <Route component={() => <div>Nothing found</div>} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: `  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/party/:partyId/" component={PartyContainer} />
    <Route excat path="/party/:partyId/partyDetails" component={PartyDetails} />
    <Route path="*" component={() => <div>Nothing found</div>} />
  </Switch>` - this is the wrapper but the point is, he enters :partyId, he takes that and passes into the function fetchWishlist(:partyId), which return data or no data. Initialy my object is empty, so it stays empty and i get the blank page. I need another page if there is no result.

Comment: Could you tell me also how to format comment in gray blocks? @CataJohn

Comment: @BojanIštvančić , you can use backticks( `` ) like this ` `test` `Be careful to not add any whitespace next to the backtick

Comment: I still have issue with this one. So basicaly i have Switch wrapper from start but the point is, if you enter :/partyId/ then you and then if you don't find anything at that point redirect should happen. Its not happening like this, i get {partyContainer} page but its without data. Thanks in advance!